# Show Entries with most common Day of the week

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get my SQL Code Work.
I have the columns "last_name" and "hired_on" and I need to get all the names
with the most common day of the week.
Example: Most common DOW for hired_on is friday so all names with people that were hired on friday get displayed

This is what I am trying to do but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT last_name, extract(dow from hire_date) 
FROM employee 
HAVING extract(dow from hire_date) = max((SELECT count(extract(dow from hire_date))))
```

Comment: break it down: 1st in a CTE; get the day of week which has the max hires.  Then in a second query using the CTE; get those that meet the criteria defined in the CTE.  Once you have that working see if you can improve performance.  note Don't mistake 1 SQL statement as being "Better" than multiple subqueries.  Complex query <> simple easy to maintain that gets the same results in roughly same effort.  BIG and complex not always as good as simple to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state how to handle ties... so I'm assuming the 1st day of a week in a tied series is ok.

[DEMO: DBFIDDLE UK 2 examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b403474c319d7373058cf8860776bdbe)

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee CTE
INNER JOIN (SELECT Extract(DOW from Hire_Date) dowMaxEmployeeHire, count(*) cnt 
            FROM Employee CTE
            GROUP BY Extract(DOW from Hire_Date)
            ORDER BY cnt Desc, dowMaxEmployeeHIre
            LIMIT 1) cj
ON  extract(dow from CTE.Hire_Date) = cj.dowMaxEmployeeHire
```

- We use a inline view/CTE either works.
- then, via a join, to allow us to join the DOW for Max employee hires to our base set dow limiting the results.

Or you could: more along what you're trying to do:

```
SELECT CTE.* 
FROM Employee CTE
WHERE  (SELECT Extract(DOW from Hire_Date) dow
               FROM Employee CTE
               GROUP BY Extract(DOW from Hire_Date) 
               ORDER BY count(*) desc, dow LIMIT 1) =extract(Dow from CTE.Hire_Date)
```

I've just never been a big fan of "SELECTS" in a where clause.